# layout not proper in visual studio design view but in browser it is perfect

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have downloaded a template from web. when i open it in visual studio 2010 the layout is not properly displayed in design view but in browser it is perfect.

template: http://www.os-templates.com/free-website-templates/academic-education-v2

Visual Studio 2010 screenshot: https://ibb.co/kVRKfa

I tried in other versions of Visual Studio. They also show the same problem. Even some other templates also show same problem. Please tell me if there any problem in the settings or any other cause. Also how to solve it...

Comment: Never used VS design view, but I would recommend that you not use it.  FYI, you may notice inconsistencies across all the various browsers.  It is good practice to check your website in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

sorry - reread your issue changing my response a bit.

Best thing to do is if you can is Debug > start without debug.

since you may need run the site in debug so that the css /js gets applied.  The .html file you see is likely disconnected from those things.